# Java Options for a specific PID

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I am using

```
java version "1.7.0_85"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.6.1) (7u85-2.6.1-5ubuntu0.14.04.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.85-b03, mixed mode)
```

currently to see JVM option values, I am using the below command
**java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version**
It prints around 720 values 
I know the meaning of these values and the type they've assigned

But, Now I want to know if I can see the JAVA options with which a particular java process has been started(JAVA Options of a running  process)

If there is any could give particulars with which I can get them.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I found what I needed

I could get that using below command

**ps aux | grep java**
which gives the below answer(with all the options that were passed)

andrews+  4940  1.1 16.9 4217936 1365804 ?     Sl   May30  37:08 /usr/bin/java -Xincgc -Xss500k -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:NewSize=8m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=150m -XX:MaxPermHeapExpansion=10m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2 -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin=0 -XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycle=5 -XX:GCTimeRatio=49 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+AggressiveOpts -Xverify:none -Dosgi.instance.area=@user.dir/Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -jar /home/local/Downloads/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -showsplash -launcher /home/local/Downloads/eclipse/eclipse -name Eclipse --launcher.library /home/local/Downloads/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140603-1326/eclipse_1605.so -startup /home/local/Downloads/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar --launcher.overrideVmargs -exitdata 32000d -vm /usr/bin/java -vmargs -Xincgc -Xss500k -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 -Xms512m -Xmx1024m -XX:NewSize=8m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:MaxPermSize=150m -XX:MaxPermHeapExpansion=10m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:ParallelGCThreads=2 -XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing -XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycleMin=0 -XX:CMSIncrementalDutyCycle=5 -XX:GCTimeRatio=49 -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=20 -XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:+AggressiveOpts -Xverify:none -Dosgi.instance.area=@user.dir/Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -jar /home/local/Downloads/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20140415-2008.jar

Comment: I believe I have misread your question. I thought you want to get the `java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal` from another process. And not simply the command line with the JVM options and parameters. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know any way to get this kind of information with any of the JDK tools (like `jcmd`).

So either you code it yourself using the [attach api](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/the_attach_api) or you might use a tool for that.

A possible way would be to use the [jvm-tools](https://github.com/aragozin/jvm-tools) (a.k.a. Swiss Java Knife).

1. get the pid of the other process

   ```
   jcmd -l
   12345 sun.tools.jcmd.JCmd -l
   6789  the.process.you.are.looking.for
   ```
2. use the sjk to get the value of the `YoungPLABSize`

   ```
   java -jar sjk.jar mx \
      -p 6789 \
      -mc \
      -b com.sun.management:type=HotSpotDiagnostic \
      -op getVMOption \
      -a YoungPLABSize
   ```

possible output

```
com.sun.management:type=HotSpotDiagnostic
name:      YoungPLABSize
origin:    DEFAULT
value:     4096
writeable: false
```